# Problem tu update tableview, Delegate Hell

Tags: ios, swift

first of all I'am renewing my votes with mobile dev almost 4 yeas without any code, a decided to start over new... so is like I'm a newvbie right now!!!

I'm creating a sort of restaurant app, where you can choose pizza, dinks and some other staff that i haven't decided yet.

My problems is..my main view controller I have a UIView and inside it a table view...
I've put a button (the pizza button) that has a segue to another view with a table view controller and data is plenty of pizza info. You have to choose a pizza and then DONE button witch sends data back to my main view controller and this view controller should populate the table view from the choice I've made in the view before.

This is my storyboard

[image]

My OrderTableViewController do this:

```
class OrderTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var orderedItems = OrderList();


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let noOrder = OrderItem()
        noOrder.itemName = "No item Yet"
        orderedItems.add(orderItem: noOrder)

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true);
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return orderedItems.list.count;
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell...
   let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = orderedItems.list[row].itemName
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = orderedItems.list[row].itemSize
    return cell
}

// MARK - Dev methods
   func updateTable(orderList:OrderList){

   // Here in this line I get que item from my other tableview   
   print("\(orderedItems.lastSelection) inside OrderTableView");


    orderedItems = orderList;
    tableView.reloadData();
}
```

Before call reloadData() I can see that that the result is correctly put on the orderedItem I can even print it
But the method reloadData does nothing.. the view keep showing "no items".

Maybe I misunderstood the whole protocol delegate pattern. 
Can you see where is it wrong?

My MainController;

```
class MainController: UIViewController, PizzaViewControllerDelegate {

var orderedItems = OrderList();
var orderTableVC = OrderTableViewController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    orderTableVC.updateTable(orderList: orderedItems);
}

func didSelectPizza(pizza: OrderItem) {

    orderedItems.add(orderItem: pizza);
    orderTableVC.updateTable(orderList: orderedItems);
}
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if segue.identifier == "orderSegue" { //embedded view -- keep controller around
              orderTableVC = segue.destination as! OrderTableViewController
          }

    if segue.identifier == "pizzaSegue"{
               let pizzaViewController = segue.destination as! PizzaViewController
               pizzaViewController.delegate = self
           }

}
```

}

My protocol for pizza:

```
protocol PizzaViewControllerDelegate {

func didSelectPizza(pizza:OrderItem);
}

protocol PizzaTableViewControllerDelegate {

    func didSelectPizzaCell(pizza:String)

}
```

My PizzaViewController

```
class PizzaViewController: UIViewController, PizzaTableViewControllerDelegate {

    var pizza = OrderItem();
    var delegate: PizzaViewControllerDelegate!;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if segue.identifier == "pizzaTableSegue" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! PizzaTableViewController;
            vc.delegate = self;
        }

    }

    //IBActions
    @IBAction func didCancel(_ sender: Any) {

        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);

    }

    @IBAction func didDone(_ sender: UIButton) {

        delegate.didSelectPizza(pizza: pizza);
        _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);
    }

    // MARK -
    func didSelectPizzaCell(pizza: String) {
        self.pizza.itemName = pizza;
       }


}
```

My PizzaTableViewControlle

```
class PizzaTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var delegate:PizzaTableViewControllerDelegate! = nil
    var pizzaMenu = PizzaMenu();
    var pizza = String();

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return pizzaMenu.menu.count;
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath);
        let row = indexPath.row;
        cell.textLabel?.text = pizzaMenu.menu[row].pizzaName;
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = pizzaMenu.menu[row].pizzaDescription;

        // Configure the cell...
        //Making the cell fancy
        //font changes
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.detailTextLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        if row % 2 == 0 {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.7)
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
        }

        return cell;
    }


 // MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        pizza = pizzaMenu.menu[indexPath.row].pizzaName;
        delegate.didSelectPizzaCell(pizza: pizza);
    }

    ///This changes cell format on the fly
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return view.frame.size.height/5.0;
    }
}
```

I'm sure that is something I haven't understood yet.. :)
Thanks!!!

Comment: You have made things a bit more complicated than they need to be by putting a tableview controller in a container rather than simply using a tableview. Your problem is that `orderTableVC` refers to a view controller instance you created, not the on from the storyboard that is on screen. You can get the onscreen instance in `prepare(for:)` the *embed* segue fires automatically when your views are loaded

Comment: Thanks.. it is true that a complicate thinks, in my head I thought that the goal was to make a controller class for each UI component to avoid blocking my main thread. Also I think, as well as in NodeJs that we have THE CALL BACK HELL, I getting in a sort of DELEGATE HELL. So, for now, I've done what you told. My MainController is also Delegate and Data Source and I put the table view directly in its storyboard.  Thanks once again...!